# Running Flask App with GUI after boot on Raspberry PI

Tags: python, flask, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to get a Flask App with a GUI with Tkinter to run on a Raspberry Pi after boot but I can't seem to get it working. I've tried to make it run on boot by putting an sh script inside /etc/init.d/ with the following instructions:

```
#!/bin/bash
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          myapp
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: My Flask App
# Description:       My Flask App with Tkinter GUI
### END INIT INFO

case $1 in
    start)
        cd /home/pi/
        python3 script.py &
        ;;
    stop)
        pkill -f 'python3 script.py'
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/myapp.sh {start|stop}"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac

exit 0
```

And then I ran the following command:
`sudo update-rc.d myapp.sh defaults`

If it helps here's a pastebin with my code: https://pastebin.com/N6QEdhUg

My Raspberry Pi is a Model 3 B+

Comment: Are you getting any tracebacks or errors during boot? Any sign that `init.d` is actually running your script?

Comment: @MattDMo I have checked the systemlogs but I didn't find anything that could relate to the script not being executed

Comment: Try putting `echo` statements as the first line in each of your `case` blocks that print a full-screen message saying what block it's in. Put a similar debugging `print` call as the first line of your Python script. You need to track down whether *anything* in `myapp.sh` is running, and where execution is failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually managed to get it working, here's what I did:

First I created an sh script named AutoStart in my user directory with the following lines:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/pi
python3 script.py
```

I then edit the autostart file with: `sudo nano /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`

And then I write on the bottom: `@sh /home/pi/AutoStart.sh`

After that I rebooted and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running it through `crontab`? An example entry would be:

`@reboot /usr/bin/python3 /path/to/script.py`

Comment: I'm not quite familiar with crontab but I found a configuration that looks like this:

[Unit]
Description=My Flask app
After=network.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=0

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
User=pi
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/script.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

I haven't had any success however as I get: update-rc.d: error: cannot find a LSB script for myapp

Comment: Try `crontab -e` (as root, if you'd like your script to run as root), and enter what I put and reboot, and see what it does. I have several Python3 scripts running on boot on my Pi and they work this way.

Comment: No luck, won't run at all. I've double checked it works by manually running it